# Updating phpmyadmin for wamp server 2.2

Tags: apache, windows-7, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

Currently I am using wamp server 2.2 with phpMyAdmin version 3.x.x
I tried upgrading it to the latest version which is 4.1.9

The step that I followed -

1 downloaded the latest version.

2 extracted it in `C:\wamp\apps`

3 copied `config.inc.php` from older version to new version folder.

4 changed the `C:\wamp\alias` to point to the latest version.

5 restarted my wamp server.

now when i try to open phpMyAdmin it gives me `http 403 forbidden` error.

why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better advised to keep the new config.inc.php as it uses a better login mechanism that does not require you storing the userid and password in the config.inc.php file, but instead throws you a login screen.

Also check your \wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file. Make sure it has this for the `Allow`

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
```

Only add the `::1` ip address if your PC has IPV6 installed and your version of apache is IPV6 aware. Basically if it throws an error about `::1` dont us it it just means you apache is not IPV6 aware.

ANOTHER THOUGHT:

I suppose when you changed the phpmyadmin.conf file to change the

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.9/"
```

you also changed the `<Directory.....>` setting accordingly?

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.9/">
```

Comment: even after adding 

`Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1`

it is throwing the same error

Comment: Have you changed the port that Apache Listens to?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the folder and files you downloaded don't have proper permissions on the file system. It's been a while since I've had a WAMP setup so I don't recall exactly what it should be, but the Apache user needs at least read permissions on the files and I believe read and execute for folders. (This is the file-system permissions and handled outside of the WAMP configuration).

Also, check your webserver error log for more details.